# Change spacing for individual QWidgets in a QGridLayout

Tags: qt, user-interface, c++11

I'm working on a project that allows users to place dominoes using a 2D grid. I made a basic version using QGridLayout and QWidgets, but realized I'd like the distance between the dominoes to be variable and based on the direction it is facing.

My question is, how can I change the spacing between individual QWidgets in a QGridLayout? I've added and image for reference. (Sorry for the low quality, had to use MS Paint)

[image]

Comment: The widgets can't all be in the same layout if you want to individually set their positioning that way. You'll need to put them into individual `QHBoxLayout`s, and stack them up in a `QVBoxLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I doubt that would work, because its a 2D grid (I guess image didn't convey this), because the elements in the same column would have to be of variable distance as well. Is it maybe smarter to create my grid manually without using layouts? Like have a parent Widget in a layout and put my cells inside that widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example program that will create 3 X 3 grid layout (main grid) and fill each cell with 3 X 3 grid layout (sub grid). Each sub grid will add a QPushButton in each side. The remaining spaces of the sub grid will be filled by QSpacerItem. This is one of a logic to achieve. Comment in the coding will explain in details.

```
void MainWindow::on_cmdGenerate_Grid_clicked()
{
    QWidget *grdParent;
    grdParent = new QWidget(this->centralWidget());
    grdParent->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 300, 300));
    //Main Grid
    QGridLayout *grdParentLayout = new QGridLayout(grdParent);
    grdParentLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("gridLayout"));
    int intTotal=-1;
    //Random position
    int intArray[] = {1,5,7,6,3,4,8,2,0};

    for(int intRow=0;intRow<3;intRow++){
        for(int intCol=0;intCol<3;intCol++){
            intTotal++;
            //Sub Grid that will sit in each cell of the main Grid
            QGridLayout *grdChild = new QGridLayout();
            int intSubTotal=-1;
            for(int intSubRow=0;intSubRow<3;intSubRow++){
                for(int intSubCol=0;intSubCol<3;intSubCol++){
                    intSubTotal++;
                    if(intSubTotal==intArray[intTotal])
                    {
                        //Adding push button in any one of the cell of sub grid 
                        QPushButton *p = new QPushButton("Hi",grdParent);
                        p->setFixedSize(33,33);
                        grdChild->addWidget(p , intSubRow, intSubCol, 1, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Remaining sub grid cells will be filled by Spacer item
                        grdChild->addItem(new QSpacerItem(33,33,QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed) , intSubRow, intSubCol, 1, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            //adding sub grid to main grid
            grdParentLayout->addLayout(grdChild,intRow,intCol,1,1);
        }
    }
    //showing the main grid
    grdParent->setVisible(true);
}

//Below code will draw boxes to visualize the Main Grid
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *paint)
{
    QPainter *p = new QPainter(this);
    for(int intX=0;intX<3;intX++){
        for(int intY=0;intY<3;intY++){
            p->drawRect(intX*100,intY*100,intX+100,intY+100);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This works well for a small number of cells, but once I have around 400 updating all the cells in a direction become slow. Does it make sense to maybe switch to a QGraphicsScene and manually manage the spacings?

Comment: @inzombiak, Yes that (QGraphicsView+GraphicsScene) will be best in case of the grid layout + spacer when getting slow.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, but the QGraphicsView worked way better and easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use a secondary grid layouts inside the main grid layout. Those secondary grid layouts will contain your domino widget and four spacers (`QSpacerItem`) defining it's position.

It's quite complex solution but it gives you complete control over widget positioning. You can play with the row stretch and column stretch values of those secondary grid layouts to obtain nice effect of "random" placement, if this is what you want.

I have prepared a small example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>650</width>
    <height>543</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
   <item>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="1" column="0">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_5">
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_15">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_16">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_15">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_16">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_13">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_14">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="1">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_7" rowstretch="0,0,0" columnstretch="0,0,0">
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_9">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_10">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_7">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_3">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_4">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_8">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="0">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_6">
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_18">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_17">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_17">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_18">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="2">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_8">
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_5">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_6">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="1">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_9">
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_8">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_12">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_13">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_11">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_14">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="2">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_10">
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_9">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_9">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_10">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_5">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_6">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_11">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_12">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_7">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer_8">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```